# How would I convert this code into a loop?

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

```
public Bee anotherDay(){
    flower = garden.findFlower();
    int pol = 5;
    bool=flower.extractPollen(pol);
    if(bool=true){  
        hive.addPollen(pol);
    }else{
        ++pol;
        bool=flower.extractPollen(pol);

        if(bool=true){  
            hive.addPollen(pol);
        }else{
            ++pol; //etc.
        } 
    }
```

The point of that code is to:

```
1)use the findFlower() method on garden ot return a flower
2)use the extract pollen method on the flower with 5 as the initial paramater
3)If there isn't 5 pollen in the flower, the method returns false so try again with 4
4)If there isn't 4 try with 3 etc. until 0.
```

I was thinking of using a for loop but I do not know how to break out of it if the method was successful and returned true, so I don't keep going to get 5+4+3+2+1 pollen from the flower.

Comment: First of all, ++pol is going increment the value, not decrement it. As such you are asking for more and more pollen each time.

Comment: haha are you still working on your beehives? :P

Comment: Haha yeah I am- It's an exercise I made up to teach myself Java and I'm making it more and more difficult as I go along =) It is becoming pretty damn complicated now though so I may have to start on something new soon so it doesn't become to tangled and confusing. After I get my worker bees to extract pollen and convert it into honey and load initial conditions from a configuration file I'm going to leave it. Hopefully one day I can come back and add a GUI but I'll leave that until I've got the basics firmly down!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
flower = garden.findFlower();
for(int pol=5; pol>0; pol--)
{
    if(flower.extractPollen(pol) {
        hive.addPollen(pol);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Added addition of pollen to hive.

Comment: Line 4 is missing a close-bracket but I can't edit it because the minimum change is 6 characters.

Comment: if I wanted to run that code twice to get 2 flowers and the pollen from it would it be best to simply copy and paste it twice or is there a better way?

Comment: Well, the `for` loop in the answer shows you how to repeat something 5 times.  Surely you can work out from this how to repeat something 2 times.